# ¿Cómo mostrar las noticias en la portada principal sin tener que realizar una consulta distinta por cada fragmento diferente?

Tags: php

La portada la tengo dividida en 4 fragmentos de diferente diseño, más adelante me gustaría agregar más fragmentos, pero por ahora esta dado a la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para cada fragmento; slider noticias, noticias destacadas, noticias relevantes, noticias en texto tengo preparado una consulta diferente por cada fragmentos, por ejemplo:

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT url,cover_page,alt_img,video,mini_title,mini_description,date_post FROM news WHERE language=? AND active=? order by id_news DESC");
$stmt->bind_param("si",$language,$active);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
  $stmt->bind_result($url, $cover_page, $alt_img, $video, $mini_title, $mini_description, $date_post);
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $urlParts = explode('=',$video); $videoId = end($urlParts);
    echo '<div class="top-grid-left-left-grids">
            <div class="col-md-8 top-grid-left-img">
              <div data-video="'.$videoId.'" id="video">'; 
                <img src="'.$cover_page.'" alt="'.$alt_img.'">
              echo '</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 top-grid-left-info">
              <a class="text" href="'.$https . $host.''.APP_RAIZ.''.$url.'">'.$mini_title.'</a>
              <p>'.$mini_descriptionA.'</p>
              <div class="t-grid">
                <ul>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><div class="tweet-time">'.facebook_time_ago($date_postA).'</div></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>';
    }
  } /*else {
}*/
$stmt->close();
```

No existe mayor problema, pero desde una sola consulta como puedo dividir la información por todos los fragmentos sin tener la necesidad de realizar una consulta diferente por cada diseño o fragmento de la portada.

Comment: Puedes traer los datos que necesites en la consulta y luego en la lectura organizar la presentación de los datos. Supongamos que el `SELECT` trae `N` columnas y que de ellas `colA, colB` van en una sección, `colC, colD` van en otra, `colM, colN` van en otra. Pues dentro del mismo `while` vas metiendo en sendos contenedores `div` los grupos de datos según lo antes dicho y luego lo presentas al salir del `while`.

Comment: @A.Cedano tengo que utilizar concatenación creo que así se llama esto: `$div .="   ";` ? Verdad, sin uso de `array`

Comment: Correcto. Podrías declarar fuera del `while` las diferentes variables, por ejemplo: `$divSlider=""; $divDestacadas=""; $divRelevantes="";` Luego, dentro del `while`  vas llenando cada uno con los datos que les corresponden, concatenado. Por ejemplo: `$divSlider.="dato colA";  $divDestacadas.="dato colC";`  etc. Luego, fuera del `while` puedes hacer `echo` de cada una de esas variables. Es mejor meter todo en cada variable, también las clases, botones, etc, para que no te hagas demasiado lío.

Comment: No entiendo porque quieres hacer eso. Muchas veces es más conveniente para la velocidad de la bd, hacer más consultas pequeñas que una sola muy grande.

Comment: @PavloB. me parece que necesita todos los datos en ese contexto, pero organizados en secciones como muestra la imagen. Eso es lo que he entendido, a no ser que se trate de otra cosa ¿?

Comment: @A.Cedano pero lo que no me queda claro es como se controla la cantidad de elementos a mostrar por ejemplo en las noticias nuevas deben ir en el fragmento noticias destacadas y, las que yo no abarcan en el número de noticias destacadas deben pasar al fragmento noticias relevantes y, el resto de noticias debe pasar al slider y a las noticias en texto.

Comment: @PavloB Causará tanto efecto realizar una sola consulta, creo que se ve más optimizado a tener que hacer distintas consultas por cada diseño diferente de la portada :(

Comment: @Mary eso ya depende de cómo tengas organizados los datos en la base de datos. Podrías por ejemplo traerlos organizados mediante el uso de `GROUP BY` o crear un JSON con ellos donde agrupes cada dato y así la lectura sea más fácil y más clara.

Comment: @A.Cedano me agrada lo que me indicas en modo `JSON` buscaré como hacerlo y, si puedes darme un ejemplo mucho mejor :) pero con todo iré investigando en la Web, gracias saludos, feliz año

Comment: @A.Cedano está una sola base de datos dónde se registran todas las noticias

Comment: No importa que sea una sola BD, una sola tabla o varias, se trata de organizar la consulta de forma que los datos vengan agrupados o estructurados y luego lees esa estructura. A mi me gusta trabajar con JSON, es bastante cómodo y en proyectos más grandes los puedes mapear a clases, etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano suena fantástico la recomendación :) tendré que aprender como hacerlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo aquí un ejemplo basado en JSON. Viendo los diseños de la imagen que pones, podemos suponer que tus datos están organizados así más o menos:

```
{"noticias": [{

    "slider": [
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Slider 1"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Slider 2"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Slider 3"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Slider 4"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Slider 5"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Slider 6"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Slider 7"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Slider 8"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Slider 9"}
    ],

    "destacadas": [
      {"text": "Texto Noticia destacada 1", "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia destacada 2", "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia destacada 3", "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia destacada 4", "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia destacada 5", "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia destacada 6", "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/50"}
    ],

    "enTexto": [
      {"text": "Texto Noticia en texto 1"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia en texto 2"}
    ],

    "relevantes": [
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Relevante 1"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Relevante 2"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Relevante 3"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Relevante 4"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Relevante 5"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Relevante 6"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Relevante 7"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Relevante 8"},
      {"text": "Texto Noticia Relevante 9"}
    ]

}]}
```

Desde la consulta a la base de datos, según tengas montado tu modelo de datos, podrás emitir un resultado así sin mayor dificultad. Incluso trabajar con estructuras de datos bien organizadas ayuda a veces a replantearse el modelo de datos para adecuarlo a las necesidades de la aplicación.

Partimos del hecho de que recibes los datos así en una variable que llamaremos `$dbData`. A partir de ahí convertiremos esa variable a un objeto JSON, y haremos la lectura para ir llenando los divs. Ahí vamos:

```
$json=json_decode($dbData);
$noticias=$json->noticias;

#Inicializamos los divs
$divSlider="<div class=\"slider has-background-warning\">";
$divDestacadas="<div class=\"destacada columns is-multiline is-mobile\">";
$divTexto="<div class=\"texto has-background-info\">";
$divRelevante="<div class=\"relevante has-background-danger\">";


foreach ($noticias as $item){
    #divs para la sección slider
    foreach ($item->slider as $slider){
        $divSlider.="<div class=\"text\"><p>{$slider->text}</p></div>";
    }

    #divs para la sección destacadas
    foreach ($item->destacadas as $destacada){
        $divDestacadas.="<div class=\"column is-one-quarter\"><img src=\"{$destacada->image}\"><p class=\"has-text-primary\">{$destacada->text}</p></div>";
    }

    #divs para la sección destacadas
    foreach ($item->enTexto as $enTexto){
        $divTexto.="<div class=\"text\"><p>{$enTexto->text}</p></div>";
    }

    #divs para la sección relevantes
    foreach ($item->relevantes as $relevante){
        $divRelevante.="<div class=\"text\"><p class=\"has-text-white\">{$relevante->text}</p></div>";
    }    

}
#Cerramos los divs
$divSlider.="</div>";
$divDestacadas.="</div>";
$divTexto.="</div>";
$divRelevante.="</div>";
#Mostramos los datos
echo $divSlider,$divDestacadas,$divTexto,$divRelevante;
```

La salida del código PHP anterior sería esta. Voy a poner unas reglas CSS simples para destacar cada sección con colores distintos y nada más. Poniendo las clases respectivas en tu contexto obtendrás el renderizado deseado.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="slider has-background-warning">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia Slider 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia Slider 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia Slider 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia Slider 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia Slider 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia Slider 6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia Slider 7</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia Slider 8</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia Slider 9</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="destacada columns is-multiline is-mobile">
  <div class="column is-one-quarter"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <p class="has-text-primary">Texto Noticia destacada 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-quarter"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <p class="has-text-primary">Texto Noticia destacada 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-quarter"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <p class="has-text-primary">Texto Noticia destacada 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-quarter"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <p class="has-text-primary">Texto Noticia destacada 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-quarter"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <p class="has-text-primary">Texto Noticia destacada 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column is-one-quarter"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    <p class="has-text-primary">Texto Noticia destacada 6</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="texto has-background-info">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia en texto 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Texto Noticia en texto 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="relevante has-background-danger">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="has-text-white">Texto Noticia Relevante 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p class="has-text-white">Texto Noticia Relevante 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p class="has-text-white">Texto Noticia Relevante 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p class="has-text-white">Texto Noticia Relevante 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p class="has-text-white">Texto Noticia Relevante 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p class="has-text-white">Texto Noticia Relevante 6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p class="has-text-white">Texto Noticia Relevante 7</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p class="has-text-white">Texto Noticia Relevante 8</p>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p class="has-text-white">Texto Noticia Relevante 9</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

*That's all folks!*

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo, me será de mucha ayuda :)

Comment: Amigo, he logrado obtener los datos en `json` pero lo otro no entiendo me sale error en esta línea `foreach ($noticias as $item)` tengo que hacer una nueva pregunta? te enlazo en un compilador lo que tengo funcionando https://ideone.com/cstm8E

Comment: @Mary no estoy seguro de que la forma en que construyes el JSON funcione y si funciona habría que ver si éste queda con la estructura esperada. Sugiero que hagas un `echo "<pre>"; print_r($valor); echo "</pre>";` y agregues en la pregunta el JSON resultante para analizarlo. O, dado que ya esta primera parte está resuelta, que abras una nueva pregunta poniendo el JSON y el error. Creo que sería lo mejor.