# ¿Cómo asignar a una variable concatenada noticias según su categoría?

Tags: php, mysqli

He agregado una nueva columna a la tabla de datos a la cual le he llamado como `main_cover` se le asignara un valor según el fragmento de la portada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las categorías o los datos existentes en la columna `main_cover` de la misma tabla `news_sport` son:

```
sidebar_right
sidebar_left
featured_news
text_news
relevant_news
```

Ahora para yo poder agregar las noticias de acuerdo al fragmento de la portada necesito que la información sea almacenada en una variable para yo poder mover e imprimir esa variable en cualquier parte de la portada principal y, para ello tengo que usar variables concatenadas ejemplo: `$divSlider .='';`

Dado desde una consulta normal:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT url,cover_page,alt_img,mini_title,mini_description,date_post,confg_img FROM news_sport WHERE language=? AND active=? order by id_news_sport DESC limit 20");
$stmt->bind_param("si",$language,$active);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

$divMainOne = $divMainTwo = Null;
$stmt->bind_result($url, $cover_page, $alt_img, $mini_title, $mini_description, $date_post, $confg_img);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $divMainOne .= '
        <div class="two-col-left">
            <div class="img-cover">
                <img src="'.$cover_page.'" alt="'.$alt_img.'">
            </div>
            <div class="heading-news">
                <a>'.$mini_title.'</a>
                <p>'.$mini_description.'</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
    $divMainTwo .= '
        <div class="two-col-right">
            <div class="img-cover">
                <img src="'.$cover_page.'" alt="'.$alt_img.'">
            </div>
            <div class="heading-news">
                <a>'.$mini_title.'</a>
                <p>'.$mini_description.'</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
```

O desde un consulta con datos `JSON`

```
$language = "es";
$active = 1;

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT url,cover_page,alt_img,mini_title,mini_description,date_post,confg_img FROM news_sport WHERE language=? AND active=? order by id_news_sport DESC limit 2");
$stmt->bind_param("si",$language,$active);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$dbData = array();
$stmt->bind_result(
    $dbData['url'],
    $dbData['cover_page'],
    $dbData['alt_img'],
    $dbData['mini_title'],
    $dbData['mini_description'],
    $dbData['date_post'],
    $dbData['confg_img']
);


$valor = "";
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $noticias[] = $dbData;
    $valor .= json_encode($noticias);
}

echo $valor;
```

Mi idea es hacerlo desde una sola consulta sin tener que realizar el mismo procedimiento para cada fragmento del diseño dividido.

Entonces como puedo asignar dicha información a una variable o varias según su categoría para que esta sea imprimida luego en su fragmento del diseño, por ejemplo:

```
Variable1 -> noticias al fragmento slider
Variable2 -> noticias al fragmento noticias destacadas
Variable3 -> noticias al fragmento sildebar o noticias relevantes
```

Y, así sucesivamente según cuantos fragmentos existan diseñados en la portada principal del blog.

Comment: En que se diferencia esta pregunta de esta anterior? https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/319578/324

Comment: @gbianchi se le asigna categorías a la respuesta y, no tenía categoría mi columna de la tabla de datos y, hasta el momento solo he podido obtener datos `json` sin poder realmente ubicar las noticias según el fragmento del diseño. En conclusión aprendí a obtener datos `json` :(

Comment: @gbianchi de la pregunta anterior a esta (según creo, luego de una serie de comentarios en otra pregunta) se llegó a la conclusión de que convenía organizar mejor los datos, para luego poder agruparlos por categorías. Una vez hecho eso, Mary, ahora el siguiente paso sería modificar la consulta SQL, haciendo que los datos vengan agrupados por categorías. Estoy se logra uniendo las tablas con `JOIN` y agrupando con `GROUP_CONCAT` y con `GROUP BY`. Si quieres construir un JSON puedes usar `CONCAT` también para ir construyendo tu JSON con los datos ordenados por categorías de noticias.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es porque estan haciendo todo este lio. Porque devolver 4 cosas distintas en un solo query? a la db no deberia costarle hacer los 4 querys si las tablas estan bien.. y solo estan agregando costo de procesamiento de algo que deberia ser bastante trivial. Cada seccion busca sus datos, y todos felices...

Comment: @A.Cedano Me gustaría aprender los dos métodos para no dejarlos en olvido, voy mirar ejemplos sobre lo que me mencionas.

Comment: @gbianchi Oh! solo está como ejemplo 4 fragmentos de diseño pero actualmente existen más fragmentos, realmente es correcto tener que hacer un `query` por cada fragmento del diseño cuando toda la información se almacena en una sola tabla de datos... si fuera distintas tablas creo que estaría bien, pero solo mostrar unas cuantas noticias para que la portada se vea elegante tener que hacer tantos `query`

Comment: @gbianchi ¿por qué no? Creo que es mejor lanzar una sola consulta y no 4, sobre todo en conexiones concurrentes como podría ser un sitio web con muchas visitas. Igualmente, si las tablas están bien hacer consultas con JOIN no va a ser para nada costoso. Si lanzas 4 querys, son 4 lecturas de datos y más código para mostrar esos datos. La carga es mayor, a mi juicio.

Comment: Si. Es correcto. Porque no vas a mostrar en todos los fragmentos lo mismo? o si? si mostraras en todos lo mismo, entonces seria un solo query y diferentes vistas. Pero esto, que parece wordpress, (y eso wp lo hace bien) es hacer una consulta por cada fragmento, aunque vengan de la misma tabla.. si no, que pasa si un fragmento es deportes, pero tus ultimas 20 noticias ninguna es de deportes?

Comment: @A.Cedano mira mi ejemplo. No, estas moviendo datos innecesarios y en muchos casos te van a faltar filas que estabas buscando.

Comment: @gbianchi no entendí tu último comentario. Yo entiendo que OP quiere una portada que agrupe los datos según presenta la imagen, en secciones distintas **pero en la misma página**. Si no es eso, si se trata de vistas distintas en páginas o situaciones distintas, es evidente que habría que hacer una query por cada vista. Lo que yo entiendo es que quiere traer la info categorizada y mostrarla con un determinado formato según la categoría.

Comment: @A.Cedano por eso decia que no entendi nunca la pregunta original. Si fueran distintas vistas segun la categoria, es wp ;) y es un query por categoria.. si es mismas notas pero vistas diferente, es un solo query, y solo cambia el formato de la pagina. Hacer un query de multiples categorias distintas con un limit, solo provocaria que algunas categorias cayeran en el olvido rapidamente.. vuelvo al ejemplo de deportes de arriba ;)

Comment: @gbianchi No, no quiero mostrar lo mismo, por eso fue mi pregunta como mostrar información sin que esta se repita dado al primer código las variables concatenadas esta me repiten la misma información, pero dado a que se va por categorías no creo que esta información se repita ahora.

Comment: Entonces mareaste al pobre Cedano que te estaba guiando hacia algo mas complejo.. Entonces si o si, es un query por seccion... no hay otra vuelta...

Comment: @gbianchi pero si lo especifique, es que si yo quisiera mostrar lo mismo yo ya lo tengo con mi primer código, ni para que preguntar por algo que ya tenia si fuera ese el caso. **Osea que obligada si o sí, tengo que hacer un `query` por cada fragmento** por otra parte que sentido tiene mostrar la misma información en distintos fragmentos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo la columna clasificación úsala como índice en un arreglo:

```
// Asumo que en bind_result incluiste $main_cover
$fragmentos = array();
$conteo = array(); // Para cada fragmento lleva un conteo de entradas
while( $stmt->fetch() ){
  $conteo[$main_cover] = ( isset($conteo[$main_cover])
                         ? $conteo[$main_cover]
                         : 0
                         ) + 1; 
  // Lógica restrictiva, Ej. Para featured_news incluimos sólo las primeras 10 entradas
  if( $main_cover == 'featured_news' && $conteo[$main_cover] >10 )
    continue;
  else{
    if( !isset($fragmentos[$main_cover]) )
       $fragmentos[$main_cover] = '';   
    $fragmentos[$main_cover] .= '<div class="two-col-left">
                                    <div class="img-cover">
                                        <img src="'.$cover_page.'" alt="'.$alt_img.'">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="heading-news">
                                        <a>'.$mini_title.'</a>
                                        <p>'.$mini_description.'</p>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                                ';
  }
}

if( isset($fragmentos['featured_news']) )
   echo $fragmentos['featured_news'];
```

No veo el caso de usar JSON para resolver un problema de clasificación.

No necesitas hacer GROUP BY en el query por que no quieres hacer agregación de datos.

Comment: Hola @Sal esto se ve fantástico, voy a mirarlo :)

Comment: una pregunta yo al `limit` puedo tener `100` pero, se puede limitar el número de resultado a imprimir a la variable por decir: `$fragmentos` que imprima solo 10 resultados de los 100 que existen en  `limit`  de la consulta.

Comment: Si, sin problema; es más fácil agregar lógica de negocio en PHP que en MySQL; actualizo con un ejemplo.

Comment: funciona amigo, pero existen unos errores, me marca error en esta línea `$conteo[$main_cover]++;` imprimiendo un error por cada registro existente de todas las categorías agregadas `Notice: Undefined index: featured_news, Notice: Undefined index: sidebar_left` y, así sucesivamente con todas y, cuando no existe dicha categoría en este caso `featured_news` imprime este error donde se hace `echo $fragmentos['featured_news'];` el error: `Notice: Undefined index: featured_news` como se soluciona amigo esos errores.

Comment: Toma en cuenta que no es un ERROR sino un NOTICE que -en este caso- no debería quitarte el sueño. No obstante, puedes inicializar todas las categorías con cero ó revisar primero si no existe con `isset` e inicializar con 1, caso contrario incrementar el contador.

Comment: cuando dice incrementar el contador, le agregas un `+` extra y, inicializar todas las categorías como la inicializas aquí me falta lección yo inicializaba una variable que conocía de su existencia pero ya en las categorías como? perdóname por mi inexperiencia

Comment: Agregué el incremento/inicialización usando un *operador ternario*, también conocido como *if en línea*.

Comment: Uy! si fue varias cosas que hiciste yo no hubiese dado... ahora el mismo aviso paso a esta línea `$fragments[$main_cover] = '`

Comment: ya se porque imprimía todos esos aviso era por que yo lo pase como concatenación `$fragmentos[$main_cover] .= '` y en tu respuesta está sin concatenación  `$fragmentos[$main_cover] = '`  es decir esto `.=` pero es que si no le agrego esto `.=` solo me imprime un resultado en cambio con la concatenación si imprime todos los resultados dichos `10`

Comment: Cierto, agregué la inicialización para hacer siempre concatenación.

Comment: Gracias ahora no se muestra esos avisos :)

Comment: amigo cuando no existe artículos en dicho fragmento o categoría `$fragmentos['featured_news'];` este me muestra un aviso de `Notice: Undefined index` como puedo personalizarlo cuando no existe artículos en dicho fragmento agregar un mensaje personalizado en vez de ese aviso.

Comment: Intenta con: `if( isset($fragmentos['featured_news']) &&  !empty($fragmentos['featured_news']) )` de la penúltima línea de mi  respuesta. Y agrega `else` con tu mensaje personalizado.